# Find Element that exists in each list in List of Lists

Tags: java, list, grails

I have a List of Lists in java (grails) and I am trying to find the elements that exist in each list within the list. Does anyone have a quick way to do this? Thank you!

Comment: *"Does anyone have a quick way to do this?"*  Ask strangers on the internet to do it for you?  [What have you tried?](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com/)

Comment: I tried the retainAll but I think that is for sets. Is there an easy way to implement sets in grails?

Comment: `retainAll` should work just fine, if you use it correctly.  Could you show us how you tried to use it and what went wrong?

Comment: I figure I have to iterate through the list to reach every list, but how do I start using the retainAll?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If lists have unique elements you can do it like this (bu unique elements I understand that one element can be placed in few lists, but only once per list. Otherwise if first list contains [1,2,2,3] and other contain [x,2,y] as output you will see [2,2] not [2] )

```
List tmpList=new ArrayList<>(lists.get(0));
for(int i=1; i<lists.size(); i++)
    tmpList.retainAll(new ArrayList<>(lists.get(i)));
System.out.println(tmpList);
```

Answer (score 0):

take 1 link list, copy it and then check that against all of the other linked lists.

if a list doesn't have an element, than remove that element from your newly made list.

you can implement your newly made list as a map or a hash table to reduce time complexity a bit.

Either way, unless your lists are sorted or something, your algorithm can't be faster than O(n) where n is the sum of all elements in all lists

the algorithm I outlined is O(nm) where m is the count of your smallest list.